# Attaching a polymorphic relationship?

Tags: laravel

I have a `user` table, `comment` table, and various other tables that can receive comments. For this example, I will define one of these tables as `post`.

## Post

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Comment', 'commentable');
}
```

## User

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment');
}
```

## Comment

```
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

Above are the relationships that relate to this question, `post` and other similar tables that can be commented on, are set up in a polymorphic way.

How can I attach a new `comment` to a `post` and attach it to the current logged in `user`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the relation in place between post and comment

```
$comment = new Comment();
$comment->user_id = $user->id;
$comment->message = $message;
$post->comments()->save($comment);
```